# How to retrieve data from realtime database in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app where the user registers, enters some information and is then redirected to another page where they can see the information they entered. The information is saved in a real time database using firebase and my problem is how to retrieve that data to display? I have looked at tutorials but i do not understand how this data is able to be retrieved in an array list or something like that.

Here is my database structure, where the id is the user's uuid:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/orNqyeq]

And here is how i save the data to the database:

this is the class constructor that holds the different variables being saved

```
  public PersonalInfo(String Id, String Name, String Birthday, String weight, String height, String gender, String Protein, String carbs, String fat, String Weightloss)
    {
        this.id = Id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Birthday = Birthday;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.Protein = Protein;
        this.carbs = carbs;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.weightloss = Weightloss;
    }
```

and after getting the text of the different text fields in the activity
the data is saved like this:

```
  PersonalInfo info = new PersonalInfo(Id, Name, Birthday, Weight, Height, Gender, Protein, Carbs, Fat, Weightloss);

        databaseinfo.child(Id).setValue(info);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If anyone could help or give me a link to a tutorial that explains my problem, it would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi just add this all into a method and call it & replace `'server/saving-data/fireblog/posts'` with your server node link and you will get the reponse from that node.

```
// Get a reference to our posts
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(PersonalInfo.class);
    System.out.println(post);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

There are several types of event listeners are present & you can read all about retrieval of data from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen this code before somewhere and i got lost with datasnapshot.getValue(Post.class); What is exactly post.class?

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it well

Comment: When you push data at some node, you create a POJO of that class and push it so the same is in the case of retrieval. pass the class reference in which data can be parsed directly

Comment: In the above example data is expected to be of type class Post.java. So in your case PersonalInfo.java will be used

Comment: ah okay understood, what about the server in getreference? Where can i get that url for my database?

Comment: That is just the path to your data in the database. So the path to the individual user you want to read.